# Best way of building a Ubuntu CMake app as cross platform on Visual Studio 2022 Community Ed. c++?

Tags: 22.04, application-development, cmake, visual-studio-code, qt-creator

Questions:

1. Are there CMake differences between Ubuntu 22.04 and Visual Studio 2019 Comm Windows 10/11?  Aside from CMake version minimum 3.20 for VS2019, I had been using 3.23 on Ubuntu.  Qt required a more complete path to find it on VS2019 `Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/lib/cmake` than on Ubuntu `Qt/6.3.1/gcc_64`.  VS2019 found some errors which Qt Creator 8.0 Ubuntu passed okay eg.

```
add_library(Feature SHARED
${SOURCES}
${HEADERS}
)
```

worked for all on Ubuntu but didn't work for a few sub modules on VS2019.  Is it just spaces or \n\r characters?  Also, `find` component REQUIRED caused fatal but is there an OPTIONAL choice in CMake so that this fatal error is avoided?;

2. How does one make the github `repos` less Ubuntu dependent eg. includes and libraries using local system paths `/usr/local/include` or `/usr/local/lib` by using non-system local directories common to both operating systems?  The shared libraries or DLLs would have to be in same place as the binaries on Windows to function or in windows/system32.;
3. How does one avoid using c:\users\username\source\repos\gitsite1\app1, c:\users\username\source\repos\gitsite2\app2, etc.?  Although path variables could be used they can get very lengthy with some apps - are there preferred ways?;
4. How does one use libraries built from source like LAPACK, Poco, SDL etc. on Windows?  Is there a `ccmake ..` for VS2019?
5. How do I get Qt Creator to recognize VS2019 Community Ed. c++ compiler.  I did not want to use mingw_64 (default) but VS2019 c++?
6. Which Fortran and ASM compilers are recommended for Windows and LAPACK?

Answer (score 0):

1. There are differences between Qt Creator 8.0 and Visual Studio 2022 Community in that CMakeLists.txt is checked differently.  Visual Studio checked and recognized the CMake formatting.  It generated more errors.  I had wondered what Windows based Visual Studio 2019 community ed. would make of an application mainly tested on Ubuntu using open-source development libraries.  I upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 on Windows and it does seem Windows is moving to become more Linux like and friendly.  MSVC Run Code Analysis option might be helpful;
2. GitHub repos were handled similarly to Ubuntu but on Windows.  The local system paths on Linux were what I was used to.  On Windows the PATH might also have to be used for DLLs - I am not certain and at present my app would run on Windows after being built on Windows from source.  I added c:\usr\local folder with \bin, \cmake, \include, and \lib subfolders.  This was a similar scheme to that used by many apps like Poco and SDL;
3. Was subjective;
4. Visual Studio 2022 replaced Visual Studio 2019 Community and seemed to have more to offer as an IDE.  I still like Qt Creator but both have a lot to offer open source dev.  Poco and LAPACK built just like on Ubuntu.  They key was configuring CMake.  LAPACK uses C and Fortran.  [2.] will have to be used, probably with PATH so that for the Ubuntu app can work on Windows as many cross-platform Linux libraries are required.  I used standalone Intel Fortran and it integrated with Visual Studio 2022.  The ability to compile a trivial C program was fixed after configuring CMake to use Fortran - which wasn't obvious to someone who just prefers to use the tools and read the instructions later;
5. Still working building Qt from source with Visual Studio - Ninja and ASM required.  The Mingw 64 the default approach worked no problem;
6. MASM (Microsoft ASM) and Intel Fortran (Beta) both were integrated with Visual Studio 2022 - some issues noted with Fortran either had been fixed or did not affect what I was doing.  I wasn't sure if the same applied to ASM and GFortran.  Use of Intel compilers may be helpful, if they are free, as improving performance on Intel technology without Nvidia GPU might be useful.  Documentation tools on Ubuntu may not have been replicated, I haven't got to that yet.

Comment: "Visual Studio 2022 community ed is available on Ubuntu now". Are you sure about that?

Comment: I am mistaken.  Sorry.